# How to replace all #{key} in string?

Tags: java, regex

I have text with multiple `#{key}` phrases. For example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing #{key1}. Proin nibh 
augue, suscipit a, scelerisque #{key1}, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel #{key2}. 
Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. 
Quisque semper #{key3} at risus.
```

I need to replace all `#{key}` values with corresponding `messageSource.getMessage(key, null, locale)` (`messageSource` is [org.springframework.context.MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html)), but i'm not good at regex. How to build right regular expression ?

**Examples**:

```
#{texts.appName} need to replace with messageSource.getMessage("texts.appName", null, locale);
#{my.company} need to replace with messageSource.getMessage("my.company", null, locale);
```

Comment: look at the String class in the api it will tell you all you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `key` is just a placeholder for any name your regex would be something like this: `#\{([\w\.]+)\}`

This means: any sequence of word characters or dots (`\w\.`, which is equivalent to `a-zA-Z0-9_\.`) between `#{` and `}` is returned as group 1.

Now you need to create a matcher and iterate over the matches, extract the key and replace the match with your message:

```
String input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing #{key1}. " +
   "Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque #{key1}," + 
   "lacinia in, mi. Cras vel #{key2}. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus." + 
   " Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper #{key3} at risus.";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "#\\{([\\w\\.]+)\\}" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );

while( m.find() ) {      
  //extract the message for key = m.group( 1 ) here
  //i'll just mark the found keys 
  m.appendReplacement( result,  "##" + m.group( 1 ) + "##" );      
}
m.appendTail( result );

System.out.println(result); //output: ... consectetur adipisicing ##key1## ...  etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this regex a try:

```
#{([^}]+)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourString.replaceAll("\\#\\{key\\}", messageSource.getMessage(key, null, locale))`

The first backslash is to escape the second backslash from java's string interpret. The second is for escaping the '#' sign (or the '{', '}' signs) for the regex interpret.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Working example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\Q#{\\E([^.]+)\\Q}\\E");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
Pattern tempPattern = Pattern.compile("([#{][^.]+[}])");
Matcher tempMatcher = tempPattern.matcher(yourString);


while( m.find() && tempMatcher.find() ) {      

    String textToReplace = messageSource.getMessage(m.group(1), null, locale);
    yourString = yourString.replace(tempMatcher.group(1), textToReplace);
}

System.out.println(yourString);
```

Hope this helps!